# WSDL2Java code generation with Spring Boot 3 jakarta dependencies - Generating setters for collection parameters

Tags: spring-boot, wsdl2java, wsimport, jakarta-migration, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate java sources from a wsdl file to integrate with my project running on Java 17 /Spring Boot 3. I am using following maven plugin setup to achieve this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <packageName>io.test.lib</packageName>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>my_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlLocation>/my_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
<!--                    <xjcArgs>-->
<!--                        <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>-->
<!--                    </xjcArgs>-->
                </configuration>
<!--                <dependencies>-->
<!--                    <dependency>-->
<!--                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>-->
<!--                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>-->
<!--                        <version>1.11.1</version>-->
<!--                    </dependency>-->
<!--                </dependencies>-->
            </plugin>
```

This works all well except the generated java files does not contains setter methods for list/collection type parameters. I was previously using the commented out plugin with Spring boot 2 to achieve this, but this is no longer working. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin has been updated to support jakarta namespace (JAXB 3 / JAXB 4)

Initial repository was [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics)
New repository location [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) (merged into the maven-jaxb2-plugin location, renamed jaxb-tools)

You can follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) since we did some change in groupId (uniformisation) and artifactId (remove `jaxb2` reference)

The configuration should look like this with updated plugin ref :

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <packageName>io.test.lib</packageName>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</wsdlDirectory>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>my_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlLocation>/my_wsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                    <xjcArgs>
                        <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>
                    </xjcArgs>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-plugins</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```